# cannot find package "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4" in any of:

Tags: go

I am getting below error while running go script

```
bash-5.1# go run lab-processor/src/main.go -inputTEXTFile=lab-processor/src/list_file.lst -TableName=public.p_labs_data
lab-processor/src/main.go:18:2: cannot find package "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4 (from $GOROOT)
        /opt/go/src/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4 (from $GOPATH)
```

I am tried `go get github.com/jackc/pgx/v4` and getting same error.

```
bash-5.1# go get github.com/jackc/pgx/v4
cannot find package "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4 (from $GOROOT)
        /opt/go/src/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4 (from $GOPATH)
```

Here is my `go env` look like

```
bash-5.1# go env
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/root/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/root/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/opt/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY="gitlab.com/TARGETPharmaSolutions/*"
GONOSUMDB="gitlab.com/TARGETPharmaSolutions/*"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/opt/go/"
GOPRIVATE="gitlab.com/TARGETPharmaSolutions/*"
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build004261076=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Also I tried `export GO111MODULE=off` and `export GO111MODULE=on` but it did not fix the issue.

Comment: Read and follow https://golang.org/doc/#getting-started. Do not use go run. Use modules.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [how to use Go](https://golang.org/doc/#getting-started).

To create a new go module, run `go mod <module_name>`.

For e.g., if I were to create a `chat-app` then I would do `go mod chat-app`.

After running it, a new `go.mod` file will be generated.

Next, in your Go file, import `github.com/jackc/pgx/v4`.

Then, run the following command

```
go mod tidy
```

It installs all the packages needed.